# Dropdown menu not working using clip-path css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, clip-path

I'm working on a navbar with diagonal side, so I use clip-path but my dropdown menus is not working. How can I fix it.

Thanks.

**SAMPLE CODE**

https://www.bootply.com/HBn3AUWrKQ

Comment: do not use external link, paste your code here which is easy to help

Comment: why you can't  try with CSS arrow instead of clip path. You can set CSS arrow in nav before to get the desired shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of clipping the whole navbar you can add a pseudo-element-triangle that is absolute positioned to the left of the sidebar which simulates the angle. It would be a better option for maintenance. Adding a new class for the angle style would also be a good suggestion. Just remove the clip-path styles and add this CSS to the .navbar:

```
.navbar-width-angle::before {
    /* dimensions and position */
    content: "";
    left: -1px; /* remove overlapping of orange-bg */
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;

    /* styles for the triangle */
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 50px 50px 0 0;
    border-color: #ffffff transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

I used this tool for css triangles: http://triangle.designyourcode.io/